# I want to change the record time dynamically

Tags: mysql

I have a quick question,

I have a select Statement like

Select * from MoneyTransactions where recordtime>='2021-05-01 00:00:00' and  recordtime<='2021-05-07 23:59:59'.

I want to dynamically change the recordtime i.e it should become >=2021-05-08  and <=2021-05-14 but the timestamp should remain the same
can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MoneyTransactions WHERE recordtime BETWEEN addtime(date('2021-05-08'),'00:00:00') and addtime(date('2021-05-14'),'23:59:59');
```

Try this, you should parameterize the date in the date function